# Parse users can't show when network connection is not available

Tags: android

i developing an social messaging app using parse backened i have successfully get the users from parse but when internet connection goes off all the data from list disappears. here is my code this is a activity where i retrieve the parse users but i can't retrieve it when my internet goes off i tried alot but can't find the way.

```
     protected List<ParseUser> mFriends;
        protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelations;
        protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;
         @InjectView(R.id.friends_search_list) ListView mListView;

//this is the method where users retrieve 

          private void retrieveUsers() {
          mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            mFriendsRelations = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstant.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
            query = mFriendsRelations.getQuery();
            query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstant.KEY_USERNAME);
            query.whereNotEqualTo("username", mCurrentUser.getUsername());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            layout.setRefreshing(false);
                            mFriends = friends;
                            String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                            int i = 0;
                            for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                                usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                                i++;
                            }
                            adapter = new MessageFriendsAdapters(MessageFriends.this, mFriends);
                            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(friends);
                            onListClick();

                        } else {
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Check your network connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Okay", null)
                                    .setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                                    .show();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Well, using the Parse SDK requires an active Internet connection. If your internet _goes off_, then no data can be transmitted to and from Parse anyway. So can you explain what's wrong with the code? That part in the `else` block, where you show the `Snackbar`, it will show up when there is an error fetching the data. That error may not **necessarily be** because of no internet.

Comment: like whatsapp or anyother app when internet connection is not available then we can see our friend list as well but in my app we can only see our friends when internet connection is available... i want to show all the list of users also in without connection

Answer (score 0):

You are using online database for your application. When you use online services you need to store them in local storage as well. There are many local storage available for android. You need to go throught them. Here is for best explanation [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

So my suggestion is First get the users from parse.com then store them in local database when you app doesn't have internet you can show the users from local database.

Hope it will help.

For example in your code it will return list of users when internet will be connected. Let's define a method `storeToLocalDatabase` for storing users. and `retrieveFromLocalDatabase()`

```
private void retrieveUsers() {
          mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            mFriendsRelations = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstant.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);
            query = mFriendsRelations.getQuery();
            query.addAscendingOrder(ParseConstant.KEY_USERNAME);
            query.whereNotEqualTo("username", mCurrentUser.getUsername());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> friends, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            storeToLocaldatabase(friends);
                            layout.setRefreshing(false);
                            mFriends = friends;
                            String[] usernames = new String[mFriends.size()];
                            int i = 0;
                            for (ParseUser user : mFriends) {
                                usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                                i++;
                            }
                            adapter = new MessageFriendsAdapters(MessageFriends.this, mFriends);
                            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(friends);
                            onListClick();

                        } else {
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Check your network connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Okay", null)
                                    .setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                                    .show();
                        }


                    }
                });

    public void storeToLocaldatabase(List<ParseUser> friends){
    //Here handle operations for storing local database
    }

   List<ParseUser> retrieveFromLocalDatabase(){
   //Handle operations to retrieve data from localstorage.
   return list;
   }
```

Comment: i also tried it but i can't save the list of users in local database it's little bit confusing

Comment: When you have internet connection you get the list of the users? right. Then you need to save it to localdata for first time. Then you need to retrieve the values from local database when your app doesn't have internet. Its simple

Comment: I have editted my anwser. I have guided you how you can do it. Now you need to understand storing data to local database.